# Is there a way in the VS Designer to remove an event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way in VS to remove the event & its associated handler using the Designer? (just trying to avoid cleaning up the compile errors associated with removing an event -- there has to be a better way)

(I know that using the VS Designer you can create a handler for an event by double-clicking the event in the Designer but how do you do the reverse -- i.e. remove it?)

Comment: AFAIK there's no other way than selecting the entire method and pressing backspace or delete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Visual Studio 2010 Event Handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905418/removing-visual-studio-2010-event-handlers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only remove the association in the designer in the **Properties Window**, clicking on the "events"-icon (a lightning symbol) and then deleting the handler method name from the respective event (right click -> **Reset**). The handler itself will remain in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete an event if you remove it from all of the controls that subscribe to it under the events section of the Properties window. Once all references are removed to that event handler, the code will also be deleted.